# Django - Passing an extra argument from template to urls.py to class-based view

Tags: django

Basically, I would like to get some advice about how to transition from a form page back to a previous page when the form is submitted.

There are other posts on similar situations but none seem to show how to implement this using a class-based view, so any advice here would be most appreciated.

So far I have come up with the approach below. Here, I am trying to pass a parameter holding the URL of the previous page, from the template for the previous page to urls.py and then onto the view. However, I don't think I am using the correct syntax in urls.py as the value of the previous_url parameter in the view is simply "previous_url".

Link in the template for the table page

```
<a href="{% url 'entry_update' item.pk %}?previous_url={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}">Edit</a>
```

URL

```
path('entry/<int:pk>/edit/', EntryUpdateView.as_view(previous_url="previous_url"), name='entry_update'),
```

View

```
class EntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'entry_update.html'
    fields = ('source', 'target', 'glossary', 'notes')
    previous_url = ""

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.updated_by = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.previous_url)
```

Update form

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.source|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.target|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.glossary|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        {{ form.notes|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-2">Update</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/entry/5131/edit/previous_url
```

Comment: instead of setting previous url you can use HTTP_REFERER for going back to previous url from where that page is initiated. For example after form save you can return as `return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this helps anyone, I was able to get the value of previous_url within form_valid() using self.request.GET.get('previous_url').

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.updated_by = self.request.user
    obj.save()
    previous_url = self.request.GET.get('previous_url')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(previous_url)
```